# 'How decode my encode xml data?

Tags: xml, asp-classic

")

    response.write "Encode = " datas &""

    ''# Stage 2
    response.write "Decode = " ''# How i again decode my encode data?

    %>

In the "Stage 1" , i encode my xml data

In the "Stage 2", How i decode the "Stage 1" Encode data?

hoping your support

Comment: Why are you URL encoding something which you are placing in the HTML output?

Answer (score 1):

Asp Classic does not supply a Decode function. You are supposed to retain the decoded bits to use it later.

In your sample:

```
<%

url="<PaginationData currentPage=""1"" totalPages=""9""/>"

''//Stage 1
datas=Server.URLencode(url)

response.write "Encode = " & datas & "<br /><br />"

''//Stage 2
response.write "Decode = " + url

%>
```